# Migrating to a custom rom

Tags: applications, backup, custom-roms

I'd like to ask if there is a way to backup all my apps and data to transfer from miui to a custom rom. I've switched before, on another device but had to reinstall everything, which was pretty annoying, thus losing all my app data. I was wondering if there is an app which just backups everything, including contacts, messages, apps and app data, etc and then restoring everything back to normal. PS. I have gained root rights.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3862763

Comment: Such an app would require root, as otherwise it hasn't access to "everything". Coming very close is e.g. Helium Backup, using a trick via ADB. Or you can use [tag:adb] backup directly – or use my tool [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) to create a backup script for that. Won't cover "everything", though: apps + data yes (unless the dev has made his app opting out of backup). Contacts + messages you'd need to transfer by other means (the contacts app allows export and import, for example).

Comment: @Izzy right. I forgot to mention that I have gained root rights on the device. I'll edit it straight away. Though helium setup didn't work, as it kept asking me to switch to ptp and that my device was on mtp when my device was actually on ptp.

Comment: @alecxs thanks a ton!

Comment: Well, if the device is rooted things look a lot different. Ever heard about Titanium Backup? I use that for about 10 years now and migrated with it many times. It's definitely worth the 5 bucks license key to go "full featured" and use all the batch stuff (though for restore I still prefer the manual way, one thing at a time). TiBu would cover "everything" you've mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I tried using the migrate app, which force closed everytime I tried to enter system apps, I went on with an app I had lying on my phone, called app2sd. I've backup up everything and I'm good to go. Thanks everyone. **Case closed**